# How to use an NPM library which executes another library's bin in its code?

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

Here's my case: I have a project P, two libraries L1 and L2. L2 provides an executable bin in its package, which was called in L1's code using `execSync` function, code like:

```
// code in library L1

import { execSync } from 'child_process';

export function foo() {
  const cmd = 'npx L2';
  return execSync(cmd).toString()
}
```

As usual, L1 has L2 as its dependency in `package.json` file.

In project P, I tried to use library L1 like this.

- First, use `npm i L1` to install library L1;
- Then, call the function `foo` like:

```
// code in project P

import { foo } from 'L1';

foo();
```

But I got an error like this:

```
Error: Cannot find module '~/project_P/node_modules/L1/node_modules/L2/index.js'
```

It seems that it went to a wrong place to find the L2's executable bin file. Because now L2 is in `project_P/node_modules`, but not in `L1/node_moudules` any more.

Also, I tried to change the `cmd` in foo like below, but none of them works.

- `cmd = 'PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH L2'`;
- `cmd = 'npm run L2'` (having script 'L2' in package.json at the same time);
- `cmd = 'node ../node_modules/.bin/L2'`;

Does anyone have a clue how to resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!